# jquery truncate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, truncate

Is there a jquery truncate plugin that doesn't have trouble with HTML in the content?

For instance this plugin does not handle HTML well:

http://www.reindel.com/truncate/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you've got the most recent version.

There's a couple more here which might may help. Can't comment on their suitability, though:

http://github.com/jsillitoe/jquery-condense-plugin/tree

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-text-truncate/

Comment: condense works for me. I can't say my testing was extensive though. But thanks.

Comment: @James Wiseman: +1; thanks for the link to jQuery Condense plugin! I put up its demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/sqDx8/1/. So people who would like to see how it works before they download it, can even try it here.

Comment: another useful jQuery plugin: **Truncatable**: http://theodin.co.uk/blog/development/truncatable-jquery-plugin.html

Answer (score 5):

[Badonkatrunc](https://github.com/plexipixel/Badonkatrunc) supports nested content in a non-destructive manner.

(Full disclosure: I am the developer of the plugin.)

Comment: This looks great. Using it now without a hitch. Thanks!

Comment: It is very nice plugin and it would be great if it was not extremely CPU intensive. See https://github.com/plexipixel/Badonkatrunc/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

Truncate plugin is good, but for my use it didn't handle p tags well enough for the read more link to reside inline.

I found success with this one: http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/02/jquery-html-truncate